# Pending tx in txpool but later tx used the nonce

Tags: python, web3py, binance-smart-chain

I have an odd issue after submitting some txs and them being in the 'pending' state but other txs used the nonces in those pending txs.

If I use web3 to get the txpool using web3.geth.txpool.content(), I see several entries from my address in the 'pending' section.  Specifically nonces 3441-3443.  If I get the current transaction count for the address, it shows 3441.  If I take a look at bscscan, I have many other successful transactions with a higher nonce than 3441....  if I wade through those entries, I am able to find successful txs that used those nonces...yet I still have the pending txs using those nonces.

If I try to replace the pending txs with a higher gas price using the nonce from the pending tx, all it seems to do is update the transaction in the txpool pending section.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out the testnet node I was connected to was all messed up.  Connecting to a different node made things works fine.